# How to resolve Mach-O Linker error for Cordova Plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, plugins, linker

I installed the latest cordova version 4.0 on my mac and am using Xcode 6.0.1

I am able to run basic cordova app, however when I tried using the plugin https://github.com/hazemhagrass/ContactPicker its failing the build. It is showing deprecated warnings at the same time throwing Mach-O Linker errors

The error Log is as follows

```
/Users/joelasirvathamjesudoss/Documents/iOS Dialer App/TeleVoIPsDialer/platforms/ios/TeleVoIPsDialer/Plugins/ContactChooser.m
/Users/joelasirvathamjesudoss/Documents/iOS Dialer App/TeleVoIPsDialer/platforms/ios/TeleVoIPsDialer/Plugins/ContactChooser.m:11:33: Assigning to 'id<ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ContactChooser *const __strong'
/Users/joelasirvathamjesudoss/Documents/iOS Dialer App/TeleVoIPsDialer/platforms/ios/TeleVoIPsDialer/Plugins/ContactChooser.m:12:26: 'presentModalViewController:animated:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h:293:1: 'presentModalViewController:animated:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
/Users/joelasirvathamjesudoss/Documents/iOS Dialer App/TeleVoIPsDialer/platforms/ios/TeleVoIPsDialer/Plugins/ContactChooser.m:40:116: 'toSuccessCallbackString:' is deprecated: Deprecated in Cordova 3.6. Use the CDVCommandDelegate method sendPluginResult:callbackId instead. This will be removed in 4.0.0
/Users/joelasirvathamjesudoss/Documents/iOS Dialer App/TeleVoIPsDialer/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVPluginResult.h:67:1: 'toSuccessCallbackString:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
/Users/joelasirvathamjesudoss/Documents/iOS Dialer App/TeleVoIPsDialer/platforms/ios/TeleVoIPsDialer/Plugins/ContactChooser.m:40:16: 'writeJavascript:' is deprecated: Deprecated in Cordova 3.6. Use the CDVCommandDelegate equivalent of evalJs:. This will be removed in 4.0.0
/Users/joelasirvathamjesudoss/Documents/iOS Dialer App/TeleVoIPsDialer/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVPlugin.h:61:1: 'writeJavascript:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
/Users/joelasirvathamjesudoss/Documents/iOS Dialer App/TeleVoIPsDialer/platforms/ios/TeleVoIPsDialer/Plugins/ContactChooser.m:41:30: 'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h:296:1: 'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
/Users/joelasirvathamjesudoss/Documents/iOS Dialer App/TeleVoIPsDialer/platforms/ios/TeleVoIPsDialer/Plugins/ContactChooser.m:23:21: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'CFIndex' (aka 'long') to 'int'
/Users/joelasirvathamjesudoss/Documents/iOS Dialer App/TeleVoIPsDialer/platforms/ios/TeleVoIPsDialer/Plugins/ContactChooser.m:53:26: 'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h:296:1: 'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
/Users/joelasirvathamjesudoss/Documents/iOS Dialer App/TeleVoIPsDialer/platforms/ios/TeleVoIPsDialer/Plugins/ContactChooser.m:56:45: 'toErrorCallbackString:' is deprecated: Deprecated in Cordova 3.6. Use the CDVCommandDelegate method sendPluginResult:callbackId instead. This will be removed in 4.0.0
/Users/joelasirvathamjesudoss/Documents/iOS Dialer App/TeleVoIPsDialer/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVPluginResult.h:69:1: 'toErrorCallbackString:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
/Users/joelasirvathamjesudoss/Documents/iOS Dialer App/TeleVoIPsDialer/platforms/ios/TeleVoIPsDialer/Plugins/ContactChooser.m:54:12: 'writeJavascript:' is deprecated: Deprecated in Cordova 3.6. Use the CDVCommandDelegate equivalent of evalJs:. This will be removed in 4.0.0
/Users/joelasirvathamjesudoss/Documents/iOS Dialer App/TeleVoIPsDialer/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVPlugin.h:61:1: 'writeJavascript:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  "_ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex", referenced from:

  "_ABMultiValueGetCount", referenced from:

  "_ABMultiValueGetIdentifierAtIndex", referenced from:

  "_ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier", referenced from:

  "_ABRecordCopyCompositeName", referenced from:

  "_ABRecordCopyValue", referenced from:

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ABPeoplePickerNavigationController", referenced from:

  "_kABPersonEmailProperty", referenced from:

  "_kABPersonPhoneProperty", referenced from:

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded to Phonegap 2.8.0 and the errors went away, however I am getting many warnings(the warnings show even when I run only the hello world app using phone gap 2.8.0).

As for the plugin itself, its invoking the iOS Contacts App, however when I select a name it is going inside the details page but the control is not getting returned to the contacts app, neither the info of my selected contact.